# youtube video not loading by id

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, jsapi

i get the code from code playground http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=youtube#change_the_playing_video

i dont know why it's not working in my pc

```
 '<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>YouTube Player API Sample</title>
<style type="text/css">
  #videoDiv { 
    margin-right: 3px;
  }
  #videoInfo {
    margin-left: 3px;
  }
</style>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("swfobject", "2.1");
</script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
  /*
   * Change out the video that is playing
   */

  // Update a particular HTML element with a new value
  function updateHTML(elmId, value) {
    document.getElementById(elmId).innerHTML = value;
  }

  // Loads the selected video into the player.
  function loadVideo() {
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("videoSelection");
    var videoID = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value

    if(ytplayer) {
      ytplayer.loadVideoById(videoID);
    }
  }

  // This function is called when an error is thrown by the player
  function onPlayerError(errorCode) {
    alert("An error occured of type:" + errorCode);
  }

  // This function is automatically called by the player once it loads
  function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytPlayer");
    ytplayer.addEventListener("onError", "onPlayerError");
  }

  // The "main method" of this sample. Called when someone clicks "Run".
  function loadPlayer() {
    // The video to load
    var videoID = "ylLzyHk54Z0"
    // Lets Flash from another domain call JavaScript
    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    // The element id of the Flash embed
    var atts = { id: "ytPlayer" };
    // All of the magic handled by SWFObject (http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + videoID + 
                       "&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=player1", 
                       "videoDiv", "480", "295", "8", null, null, params, atts);
  }
  function _run() {
    loadPlayer();
  }
  google.setOnLoadCallback(_run);
</script>
```

Loading...

Select a video to load:

YouTube API Overview
          Ninja Cat
          Beatboxing Flute
        
      
    
    
  
'

Answer (score 0):

From Google Chromeless API:

Note: To test any of these calls, you must have your file running on a webserver, as the Flash player restricts calls between local files and the internet. [1]

Why don't you try on-line demo? [2]

[1] http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#GettingStarted

[2] http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/youtube_player_demo.html?playerType=chromeless&playerVersion=as3